# How to delete the bottom white line in vim?

Tags: vim, syntastic

Once I installed syntastic, this white line shows up, but now i dont want that anymore, and it stays even if i have deleted the plugin.
How can i eliminate that?
[white bar click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59F2o.jpg)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/619765/hiding-vim-command-line-when-its-not-being-used).

Comment: You have `laststatus=2` in your vimrc. You should decide if you don't really want it in there. (AFAIK it has nothing to do with syntastic)

Comment: sry, I dont have laststatus=2 inmy vim rc

Comment: @orlp this is not my command line it seems to be a line reserved for syntactic

Comment: Is that your vimrc? Do you have airline installed? If yes, do you know what airline does?